# Background color of textfield in Android default browser changes on click

Tags: android, html, css

I have a textfield in my html page with css

```
#textField {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Thus showing a text field with black background color and white text.This works fine in all desktop as well as iPad browsers.

But in Android default browser while on clicking the text field the background color changes to white and text color to black.

Please mention how to override this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please include the following code in your css to avoid overriding of background color in android browser

```
#textField {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
}
```